# RegEx Capture Multiple Repeating Optional Fields?

Tags: regex, vb6, regex-group

Fairly new to RegEx, go easy on me. I was wondering if you can capture multiple repeating optional fields? For instance, this URL has multiple RELATED meta-value fields. But some URL's only have one meta, others have 3+. The below RegEx will optionally only capture the first meta value.

My source now only needs to capture less than 4 metas, so I could just paste repeating: `(((?!meta-value).)+meta-value">([^<]+))?` in the RegEx to capture the first four.

However, I was wondering if there was a better way. I considered capturing the meta in a separate RegEx, but they are related to the URL, so I was trying to capture them at the same time.

Example RegEx:

```
<a href="([^"]+)(((?!meta-value).)+meta-value">([^<]+))?
```

Example Text (first URL has two meta-value categories, second URL only has one):

```
bla bla <a href="testurl.html"> bla bla <div id="meta-value">Category</div> bla bla bla <div id="meta-value">Diff Category</div> bla bla <a href="testurl2.html"> thsdlkjfh <div id="meta-value">Category2</div> bla bla bla
```

http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97173

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What would be expected outcome from example string

Comment: To capture the testurl.html's and all of its associated meta-values. And yes the code does work, the question is, do I need to repeat (((?!meta-value).)+meta-value">([^<]+))? over and over again to capture all of the meta-value's or is there a way to capture them all without mindless copy/pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completly understand the desired outcome but if you are looking for the contents of each `div` element within each `<a>` tag then I would suggest two matches.

The first should get all the `<a>` tags and their contents: `<a href="(.+?)".*?<\/a>` with a capture group for the url if you desire

Then iterate over the list of `<a>` tags  you just created and use this expression to pull out the meta parts: `<div id="meta-value">(.*?)<\/div>`

You can play around with these expressions [here](https://regex101.com/r/drPFpQ/1).

If this doesn't satisfy the outcome you expect please clarify further.

Comment: Yeah I ended up having to (in VB6 use (NextMatch).FirstIndex - FirstIndex + Length to) get the sub-string between the <a> matches and run sub RegEx to find all the meta-values. Thanks